# For an infinite dataset, is the data used in each epoch the same?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow, suppose I have a dataset from generator:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen...)
```

and this generator generates **infinite nonrepetitive** data (just like infinite non-cyclic decimals).

```
model.fit(dataset, steps_per_epoch=10000, epochs=5)
```

Now within these 5 epochs of training, is the data used the same? i.e. always the first 10000 items from the generator? rather than 0-9999 for epoch 1, 10000-19999 for epoch 2,etc.

What about the `initial_epoch` parameter? If I set it to be 1, will the model be trained from the 10000th item?

```
model.fit(dataset, steps_per_epoch=10000, epochs=5, initial_epoch=1)
```

**update :**
this simple test shows that the dataset will be reset every time `model.fit()` is called

```
def gen():
    i = 1
    while True:
        yield np.array([[i]]), np.array([[0]])
        i += 1

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, output_types=(tf.int32, tf.int32)).batch(3)

x = Input(shape=(1, 1))
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=x)

model.compile('adam', loss=lambda true, pred: tf.reduce_mean(pred))
for i in range(10):
    model.fit(ds, steps_per_epoch=5, epochs=1)
```

output:

```
1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.0000
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 8.0000
1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.0000
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 8.0000
1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.0000
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 8.0000
1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.0000
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 8.0000
1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.0000
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 8.0000
1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.0000
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 8.0000
1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.0000
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 8.0000
1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.0000
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 8.0000
1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.0000
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 8.0000
1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.0000
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 8.0000
```

5 epochs in 1 call:

```
model.fit(ds, steps_per_epoch=5, epochs=5)
```

output:

```
Epoch 1/5
1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.0000
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 8.0000
Epoch 2/5
1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 17.0000
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 23.0000
Epoch 3/5
1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 32.0000
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 38.0000
Epoch 4/5
1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 47.0000
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 53.0000
Epoch 5/5
1/5 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 62.0000
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 68.0000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the data used is different. `steps_per_epoch` is used by `keras` to determine the length of each `epoch` (as generators got no length), so it knows when to end the training (or call checkpointers etc.).

`initial_epoch` is a number displayed for epoch and useful when you want to restart training from checkpoint (see [fit method](https://keras.io/models/sequential/)), it has nothing to do with data iteration.

If you pass the same `dataset` to `model.fit` method, it will reset after each function call (thanks for the info OP).

Comment: Thanks for reply. What if I put it in a for loop?  Now in each iteration, `model.fit(...epochs=1)` is activated repeatedly. In this case, will the dataset be reset in each loop, causing the same data generated?

Comment: No, it won't reset in each loop, `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen...)` will act just like Python generator. Extended answer, not sure if needed though.

Comment: I did a test, which shows the dataset will be reset every time model.fit() is called.

Comment: Surprising, thanks for the info, updating my answer.